# Weird problem with a kata on codewars (python)

Tags: python, multiplication

[Kata description](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55685cd7ad70877c23000102/discuss):

> In this simple assignment you are given a number and have to make it negative. But maybe the number is already negative?
> Example:
>
> ```
> Kata.MakeNegative(1); // return -1
> Kata.MakeNegative(-5); // return -5
> Kata.MakeNegative(0); // return 0
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> - The number can be negative already, in which case no change is required.
> - Zero (0) is not checked for any specific sign. Negative zeros make no mathematical sense.

Ok so this kata asks me to make any number into a negative, I know I can do it with if, but I wanna see it work this way:

```
def make_negative( number ):
    number = ((number)*(-1))
    return number
```

When I test it works, but when I attempt it I get this: "9 should equal -9" even though it's a basic test case that I passed earlier (I also get the same error on the random test cases). Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah that's the weird thing, when I try it in any other compiler it works flawlessly, when I do it in codewars I get this:
"Basic Test Cases
Test Passed
9 should equal -9
Test Passed
Completed in 0.02ms"

Comment: If number is negative (-9), then your function makes it positive. That probably makes it fail some of the test cases (i.e. your function returned 9 when it should be -9). Though we can only guess since it's not clear what the expected results and test cases are.

Comment: How do you do this with `if` and without multiplying by `-1`?

Comment: @Nafikos That message says it passed. Why do you think there's a problem?

Comment: @Barmar It's weird, the test says it passes right, them I press attempt and it says it didnt pass. It didnt work with if either and I dont get what the issue is since the test passes flawlessly. I was thinking using if for each specific case but it still gets the same error

Comment: I think you need to post the exact text of the kata.

Comment: Is it [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55685cd7ad70877c23000102/discuss)?

Comment: The answer with `abs()` should work, you must be doing something wrong when you copied it.

Comment: @Barmar yep it's this exact one

Comment: Your code will turn `-5` to `5`, it's supposed to leave it as `-5`. The answer below should work.

Answer (score 1):

To make an *always negative result* I'g suggest the use of [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) combied with the `-1` multiplication

```
def make_negative(number):
    return -1 * abs(number)

print(make_negative(10))  # -10
print(make_negative(-10))  # -10
```

Comment: Yeah it still messes up, I'll just bite the bullet and use if I guess, thanks for the comment though, have a great day sir

Comment: What is the `if` statement that works better than this? @Nafikos